# Symfony2 outputting pdf using FPDF

Tags: symfony, pdf

How do I return a response in Symfony to output a pdf? I'm currently using FPDF as I don't want to use any bundles. Here is my controller action:

```
public function pdfAction(Request $request) {

    //grab from database

    $pdf = new \FPDF;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($entities); $i++) {
        //manipulate data

       $pdf->AddPage();
       $pdf->SetFont("Helvetica","","14");
       $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 255, 255);
    }

    $pdf->Output();

    return new Response($pdf, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'pdf'));

}
```

With this all I'm getting is a page with gibberish characters. I'm quite new to I/O manipulations so any help would be great. Thank you..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set proper `Content-Type` of your response. Also, don't send your `FPDF` object as a content of your response, but rather the PDF output. Try this:

```
public function pdfAction(Request $request) {

    //................//

    return new Response($pdf->Output(), 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));

}
```

**UPDATE:**

To get your generated PDF file downloaded instead of displayed, you need to set `disposition` to `attachment`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ResponseHeaderBag;

public function pdfAction(Request $request) {

    //................//

    $response = new Response(
        $pdf->Output(),
        Response::HTTP_OK,
        array('content-type' => 'application/pdf')
    );

    $d = $response->headers->makeDisposition(
        ResponseHeaderBag::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT,
        'foo.pdf'
    );

    $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', $d);

    return $response;
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#serving-files

Comment: so simple. Thank you! How can I get the file to be downloaded instead of it showing on the browser?

Comment: Original answer (update not tested) works with Symfony 4 too.

Answer (score 2):

In symfony 2.7, I'm having a "Corrupted content" while trying to set the Content-Disposition. My fix is:

```
public function pdfAction(Request $request) {

//................//

$response = new Response(
    $pdf->Output(),
    Response::HTTP_OK,
    array('content-type' => 'application/pdf')
);

return $response;
}
```